# How can I make an audio file overlap itself?

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Currently I'm using mediaelement to play an audio file when I click a button. Though if I double tap the button, the sound only plays once. I would like to find a way to make the sound play every single time I push the button without having to wait for the file to finish playing.

Comment: I removed the tags from your title - they are redundant there.

Comment: When you say overlap it sounds like you are looking to have the first instance continue playing and launch a second instance to play the file again.  Is that what you want or do you want to stop the first instance and play the file fresh?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to continue playing the first, along with creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manage the click event on the button (or launch a command) that starts a thread in which the sound is played.
Each time you click the button, you start a new thread.